# Preprocessor swaps arguments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

I have some code that needs a value in a text representation and the same value as hexadecimal representation. I need both but to take away a potential source of errors I want to specify the values only once and let the preprocessor taking care of it.

Here is an exampe of one item.

```
int[]   v = { 0x01, 0x02 };
LPCTSTR s = L"0102";
```

Preprocessor concatination is a powerfull help in this.
Here is the same code but now via preprocessor commands.

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x)  STRING2(x)

#define _S(t) _T(STRING2(t))
#define _H(t) 0x ## t

#define _VS(a,b) _S(a) _S(b)
#define _VH(a,b) _H(a),_H(b)

LPCTSTR s = _VS(01, 02);
int[]   v = { _VH(01, 02) };
```

The the code generated by the preprocesor looks like this:

```
int[]   v = { 0x01,0x02 };
LPCTSTR s = L"01" L"02";
```

But I'm still repeating my data. So, I try this.

```
#define ARGUMENTS 01, 02

LPCTSTR s = _VS(ARGUMENTS);
int[]   v = { _VH(ARGUMENTS) };
```

And now the preprocessor code is broken!

```
int[]   v = { 0x01, 02,0x };
LPCTSTR s = L"01" L;
```

Note that the second argument and the token part with which it should be concatinated is swapped or missing.  But why?

The [VS2010 help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22%23%23%22);k(DevLang-%22C%2B%2B%22);k(TargetOS-WINDOWS)&rd=true) is not helping me much. It tells me that the concatination operator is putting constrants on macro expantion. Than is most likely the reason why expanding macro ARGUMENTS is going foobar.
But how can I get this to work?

Extra testing showed that it is definitely the concatination operator that stops further expantion of macro's. So I need a way to expand the arguments first and then use the concatination operator. Good idea? Now the how!

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ARGUMENTS` is still a single value, a thing that you clearly see in both outputs - `ARGUMENTS` treated as a single parameter, followed by the treatment of the second **empty** parameter (gcc is actually more helpfuls and throws away the preprocessing with `error: macro "_VS" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given`).

To achieve what you want, try this:

```
#define MK_STRING_INT_PAIR(a,b,sname,vname) \
LPCTSTR sname=_VS(a,b); \
int[]   vname={_VH(a,b)};

MK_STRING_INT_PAIR(01,02,s,v)
```

[Edit]
If you need more than 2 values, write a short program to generate a .h file with macros on the line of:

```
#define MK_PAIRS_2(sname,vname,v0,v1) ...
#define MK_PAIRS_3(sname,vname,v0,v1,v3) ...

#define MK_PAIRS_128(sname,vname,....
```

Being generated, you won't need to rely on the _VS, _VH helper macros

(I feel in my bones in C++11 there is the potential to use variadic templates and constexpr-s of char[] type to do it, but for now I don't have the time to explore it).

Comment: You are right, the preprocessor is not swapping. The 'first' argument is the whole of ARGUMENTS. It appears to be swapping. A simple test where ARGUMENTS is extended to '01,02,03' did show me that. So the correct title for this thread should be 'Preprocesor is not parsing arguments'.

Comment: @PapaAtHome "'Preprocesor is not parsing arguments'." Of course not, it never did.

Comment: the 'Of course not' for you is a 'Oh thats happening' for me. With your help I learned something. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @PapaAtHome You are welcome. After all, that what SO is for.

Comment: General remark: The answer by @StoryTeller is just as valid, but I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

I get the feeling you should rewrite your definition as [XMacros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387). It's a nifty technique that will have you write one file (typically with a `.def` extension) that contains the data definition, like this:

```
VAL(01)
VAL(02)
```

Than you simply define a proper macro, and include to get the desired structure, like so:

```
#define VAL(x) _H(x),
  int[]   v = {
  #include "values.def"
  };
#undef VAL

#define VAL(x) _S(x)
  LPCTSTR s =
    #include "values.def"
  ;
#undef VAL
```

Comment: I can see how this works. And a very interesting article about XMacros! Where this solution is more or less 'depth first' the solution suggetsted by Adrian Colomitchi is more or less 'breath first'. Both techniques will work, now I can choose what I want to use.